# Visual increment and decrement button controls in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

I currently have a working implementation of a + and - tank level thingy (I don't really know what to call it). In which will be able to 'add' or 'remove' so-called 'liquid' from the container.

However, I feel my implementation of this is very inefficient, and would appreciate your input on this matter.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {


   $('#plus1').click(function() {
     var myVal = $('.loadingTank').css("box-shadow");
     var x = myVal.slice(-1); 
     if (x == 't') {
       myVal = myVal.split(" ")[4];
     } else {
       myVal = myVal.split(" ")[2];
     }
     myVal = -(parseInt(myVal, 10) / 5);
     if (myVal <= 99) {
       myVal += 1;
     }
     if (myVal < 11) {
       $('.loadingTank').css("background-color", "red");
     } else {
       $('.loadingTank').css("background-color", "#808080");
     }
     if (myVal > 99) {
       $('#tankPercentage').text("FULL");
     } else {
       $('#tankPercentage').text(myVal + "%");
     }
     myVal = myVal * 5;
     $('.loadingTank').css("box-shadow", "rgb(56, 56, 56) 0px -" + myVal + "px 0px -2px inset");
   });


   $('#minus1').click(function() {
     var myVal = $('.loadingTank').css("box-shadow");
     var x = myVal.slice(-1);
     if (x == 't') {
       myVal = myVal.split(" ")[4];
     } else {
       myVal = myVal.split(" ")[2];
     }
     myVal = -(parseInt(myVal, 10) / 5);
     //gets percentage of tank //myVal=Math.round(myVal);
     if (myVal >= 1) {
       myVal -= 1;
     }
     if (myVal < 11) {
       $('.loadingTank').css("background-color", "red");
     } else {
       $('.loadingTank').css("background-color", "#808080");
     }
     if (myVal < 1) {
       $('#tankPercentage').text("EMPTY");
     } else {
       $('#tankPercentage').text(myVal + "%");
     }
     myVal = myVal * 5;
     $('.loadingTank').css("box-shadow", "rgb(56, 56, 56) 0px -" + myVal + "px 0px -2px inset");
   });


 });
```

```css
.loadingTank {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 15px;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #808080;
  box-shadow: rgb(56, 56, 56) 0px -200px 0px -2px inset;
  /*Change this value for leveling*/
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
.loadingTank:before {
  content: "";
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), color-stop(100%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#66000000', endColorstr='#00d0d0d0', GradientType=1);
}
.loadingTank:after {
  /*idea is for this to be the 'leveling'*/
  content: "";
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightGray;
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 1%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 11%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 21%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 29%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 30%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 31%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 39%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 41%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 61%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 69%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 71%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 79%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 81%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 90%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 91%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 99%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(1%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(9%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(11%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(19%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(21%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(29%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(31%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(41%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(49%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(59%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(61%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(71%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(79%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(81%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(89%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(91%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(99%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 1%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 11%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 21%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 29%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 30%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 31%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 39%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 41%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 61%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 69%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 71%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 79%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 81%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 90%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 91%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 99%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 1%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 11%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 21%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 29%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 30%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 31%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 39%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 41%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 61%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 69%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 71%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 79%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 81%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 90%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 91%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 99%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 1%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 11%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 21%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 29%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 30%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 31%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 39%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 41%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 61%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 69%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 71%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 79%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 81%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 90%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 91%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 99%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 1%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 11%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 21%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 29%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 30%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 31%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 39%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 41%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 61%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 69%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 71%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 79%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 81%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 90%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 91%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1) 99%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demoOptions">
  DEMO PURPOSES ONLY
  <button id="plus1">+</button>
  <button id="minus1">-</button>
</div>

<div class="loadingTank">
  <div id="tankPercentage" style="position:absolute; font-size:x-large; color:white;">40%</div>

</div>
```

My thoughts are that the jQuery can most likely be optimized here:

```
 $('#plus1').click(function () {
            var myVal = $('.loadingTank').css("box-shadow");
            var x = myVal.slice(-1);//required as a workaround to find out whether IE or not
            if (x == 't') { //other browsers
                myVal = myVal.split(" ")[4];
            }
            else { //is ie
                myVal = myVal.split(" ")[2];
            }
            myVal = -(parseInt(myVal, 10) / 5);
            if (myVal <= 99) {
                myVal += 1;
            }
            if (myVal < 11) { //'alarm' if 10% left or lower
                $('.loadingTank').css("background-color", "red");
            }
            else {
                $('.loadingTank').css("background-color", "#808080");
            }            
            if (myVal > 99) {
                $('#tankPercentage').text("FULL");
            }
            else {
                $('#tankPercentage').text(myVal + "%");
            }
            myVal = myVal * 5;
            $('.loadingTank').css("box-shadow", "rgb(56, 56, 56) 0px -" + myVal + "px 0px -2px inset");
        });
```

Any advice? As you can probably tell, I'm not very good at implementing jQuery.

Comment: Not sure what the CSS values are supposed to be doing here. Maybe a working demo in Codepen or Jsfiddle would help

Comment: @Dbugger: Please see working code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can refactor it with the DRY principle:

```
$('#plus1').click(function () {
  var myVal = getBoxShadow($('.loadingTank'));

  myVal = -(parseInt(myVal, 10) / 5);

  if (myVal <= 99) {
    myVal += 1;
  }

  displayAlarm($('.loadingTank'), myVal);
  displayValue($('#tankPercentage'), myVal);

  myVal *= 5;
  $('.loadingTank').css("box-shadow", "rgb(56, 56, 56) 0px -" + myVal + "px 0px -2px inset");
});

function getBoxShadow($element) {
  var value = $element.css("box-shadow"),
      x = value.slice(-1);
  return x === "t" ? value.split(" ")[4]: value.split(" ")[2];
}

function displayAlarm($element, value) {
  var color = value < 11 ? "red": "#808080";
  $element.css("background-color", color);
}

function displayValue($element, value) {
  var text;

  if (value > 99) {
    text = "FULL";
  }else if (value < 1) {
    text = "EMPTY";
  }else {
    text = value + "%";
  }

  $element.text(text);
}
```

I also think it's good to move the color "red" and "#808080" to your CSS class, and then change `.css('background-color', 'xxx')` to be `.addClass`, `.removeClass` or `.toggleClass`.